# Gradients with Javascript both radial and linear?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to make CSS3 like gradients with Javascript? For cross browser compatibility? CSS3 doesnt work in some browsers so I am looking for alternatives. How can I use Javascript to make cross browser compatible gradients? Both linear and radial gradients

Comment: Yall want to mark down my post cause you dont know the answer. This is a legit question many people can learn from.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really think of a practical way that JavaScript is going to solve this for you, these sort of presentational issues aren't really in JavaScript's wheelhouse.

I think the best linear-gradient alternatives are going to be CSS-based, like creating a png of your gradient, and setting that as the background-image.

Older browsers ignore CSS they don't understand, so something like this would provide a linear gradient for modern browsers and a fallback image for older browsers:

```
.example {
  background-image: url(my-gradient.png);
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, red, blue);
}
```

The most practical thing to do would just be to set a background color that splits the difference, and not worry about having perfect representation for older browsers:

```
.example {
  background-color: #720090;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, red, blue);
}
```

Keep in mind that [CSS support is for linear-gradient](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) is pretty darn good.  The only major browsers missing it are IE8 and IE9, both of which are circling the drain.